# Creating and accessing buttons dynamically PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I want to create buttons after some processing according to the results, and I want them to be clickable.

Here's what I tried :

```py
for action in actions:
    name = action[2]
    button = QPushButton(name, self.timelineFrame)
    dir = "actions/{}.mp4".format(name)
    button.move(...)
    button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.OpenVid(dir))
    button.show()
```

The self.OpenVid function opens a video with VLC.

The problem is that every button opens the same video, the last one in the list of actions. 
As if **button.clicked.connect** had overwritten every buttons from previous loops.

I've tried using **self.button** and renamed them like this at the end of each loop:

```
rename_attribute(self, "button", "button_{}".format(name))
```

With the function :

```
def rename_attribute(object_, old_attribute_name, new_attribute_name):
    setattr(object_, new_attribute_name, getattr(object_, old_attribute_name))
    delattr(object_, old_attribute_name)
```

But I got the same results : **self.button.clicked.connect** still seems to rewrite the other buttons even if they have different names.